# Is it possible to asynchronously call a jQuery function on differing intervals for each <div> in a given class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

I have a function to loop through each `<div>` in a class as such:

```
var UPDATE_MIN = 5 /*seconds*/ * 1000;
var UPDATE_MAX = 10 /*seconds*/ * 1000;

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".class").each(function(){

        // generate a random update interval
        var interval = UPDATE_MIN + Math.floor(Math.random() * UPDATE_MAX);

        function update_class() {

            // do some junk here

            // update interval and carry on
            interval = UPDATE_MIN + Math.floor(Math.random() * UPDATE_MAX);
            setTimeout(update_class, interval);
        }

            update_class();
    });
});
```

The goal is to have the function `update_class` run on varying intervals for each of the `<div>` elements in the class `.class`. This should produce a random sequence of changes across the `<div>` elements over time. My current understanding of jQuery tells me that this will not work since jQuery runs synchronously. Am I heading in at least the right direction to get this done? Any advice or direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: it isn't jquery that runs synchronously, it's javascript. setTimeout is one way of breaking out of that and making something asynchronous-like. So, yes, you are looking in the right direction for what your goal is.

Comment: Or, you can try a web worker.

Comment: this should be fine... except for the interval calc, I think it should be `UPDATE_MIN + Math.floor(Math.random() * (UPDATE_MAX - UPDATE_MIN));`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BDv89/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Arun P Johny: jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BDv89/1